# Literal types and default values in props (Vue 3 Typescript)

Tags: typescript, properties, vuejs3, literals, vue-composition-api

I am familirizing myself with Vue 3 and TypeScript. I am currently facing a problem when appling literal type for component's property. The idea is to have a `border` prop accepting 3 fixed values (sm, md, lg) as string and having default value as "md".  But when I tested this component by passing in "sm" (or even md or lg), I received this error from TypeScript: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ type: PropType<Size>; required: false; default: string; }'.`

Here is the code of the component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import type { PropType } from "@vue/composition-api";

type Size = "sm" | "md" | "lg";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "RoundedPicture",
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    alt: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    border: {
      type: String as PropType<Size>,
      required: false,
      default: "lg",
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const BORDER_WIDTH_SIZE_MAPPING: Record<Size, string> = {
      sm: "p-0.5",
      md: "p-1",
      lg: "p-1.5",
    };

    return { BORDER_WIDTH_SIZE_MAPPING, props };
  },
});
</script>
```

Here is how I used it:

```
<RoundedPicture
  class="w-full"
  border="sm"
  src="https://picsum.photos/id/39/300/300"
  alt="avatar"
/>
```

And here is the full message of the error:

```
(property) border?: {
    type: PropType<Size>;
    required: false;
    default: string;
} | undefined
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ type: PropType<Size>; required: false; default: string; }'.ts(2322)
RoundedPicture.vue(21, 5): The expected type comes from property 'border' which is declared here on type 'ComponentProps<ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{ gradient: boolean; border: { type: PropType<Size>; required: false; default: string; }; }> & Omit<...>; ... 10 more ...; $watch<T extends string | ((...args: any) => any)>(source: T, cb: T extends (...args:...'
```

Does anyone have a solution for this circumstance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try `:border="'sm' as const"`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work